# How to use Primefaces' p:growl and redirect to a page

Tags: jsf, redirect, primefaces, growl

hi im kind of new at jsf enviroment, im trying to update a primefaces growl and then redirect to a page from a commandButton action.

```
 <p:commandButton value="Guardar"  action="#{AgendamientoMBean.procesaAgendamientoJ()}" 
 update="growlDetalle" />
```

The managed bean code its

```
   FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
   context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, descripcion, detalle));
   ....
   ....
    return "agp_bandeja_citas_llamadas?faces-redirect=true";
```

This only redirectme to the page but doesnt show me the growl message, i tested that if change my method to not return the page the message does show..

I was trying to update the growl of the page that im redirecting but thats impossible i guess.

i think that when redirecting i lost the update functionality because im in new page now.

Is there a way to tell jsf to first do the update and then redirecting?

Hope you can help me, 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Messages get lost during redirect. You can use the flash to keep messages.

Add the following before returning from your action method:

```java
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
```

Comment: Note that this approach has a peculiar bug when used with Mojarra: it won't work then the redirect goes to a different path. If the current and target page are in the same path (the same folder in URL), then it will work fine. See also http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1877

Answer (score 1):

Add another growl to page you redirect

like this
`<p:growl id="growlmsg2" showDetail="true" sticky="true" autoUpdate="true"/>`

Answer (score -1):

Because Flash has bug, my solution is to make a separated redirect button which will be hit after showing msg:

HTML:

```
<h:form prependId="false">
    <p:growl />
    <p:button outcome="gotoABC" id="rdr-btn" style="display: none;" />
    <p:commandButton action="#{bean.process()}" update="@form" />
</form>
```

Bean:

```
public void process(){
    addInfoMsg(summary, msgDetail); //Add msg func
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("setTimeout(function(){ $('#rdr-btn').click(); }, 3000);"); // 3 seconds delay. I put the script in Constants to config later.
}
```