# Primefaces growl is not working in all the pages

Tags: jsf, primefaces

My web has a common template i.e. `xhtml file` while contains `growl`

```
<p:growl id="message" showDetail="true" life="3000" />
```

This template is used further in all pages. I noticed that `growl` is working for page `index.xhtml` but not working in rest of the pages. Below is the snippet of `faces-config.xml` file-

```
<navigation-rule>
    <display-name>index.xhtml</display-name>
    <from-view-id>/index.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>NORMAL_USER</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/home.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

But whenever I am accessing the page `home.xhtml` via link `http://localhost:8080/portal/home.xhtml`,  `growl` starts working. In all the pages I am using `update=":message"` to update `growl`. Which is the culprit?

Below is `index.xhtml`

```
<ui:composition template="/template/common/base.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <ui:define name="center">

        <h:form>
            <div align="center" style="margin-top: 10%; margin-bottom: 10%;">
                <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <f:facet name="header">  
                     #{msg.HEADER}
                    </f:facet>

                    <h:outputLabel for="username" value="#{msg.USERNAME}" />
                    <p:inputText id="username" value="#{client.user.username}"
                        required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg.USERNAME_REQUIRED_MSG}" />

                    <h:outputLabel for="password" value="#{msg.PASSWORD} " />
                    <p:password id="password" value="#{client.user.password}"
                        required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg.PASSWORD_REQUIRED_MSG}" />

                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <div align="right">
                            <p:commandButton value="#{msg.LOGIN_BUTTON}" icon="ui-icon-check"
                                update=":message" action="#{client.login}" />
                        </div>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:panelGrid>
            </div>
        </h:form>

    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Below is `base.xhtml`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>My Web Portal</title>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="default.css" />
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <p:growl id="message" showDetail="true" life="3000" />

    <h:link outcome="index" style="text-decoration: none;">
        <div id="header" style="margin: 2px; width: 100%; text-align: center;">
            <p:panel>
                <h:outputText value="My Web Portal"
                    style="font-size: 20px; " />
            </p:panel>
        </div>
    </h:link>

    <div id="middle" style="margin: auto; width: 80%;">
        <ui:insert name="center"></ui:insert>
    </div>

    <div id="footer"
        style="clear: both; text-align: center; margin: 2px; width: 100%;">
        <p:panel header="2013 All rights reserved. Designed by Ravi Joshi">
            <h:link value="Home" outcome="index" />
            <p:spacer width="10px;" />
            <h:link value="About Us" outcome="index" />
            <p:spacer width="10px;" />
        </p:panel>
    </div>

</h:body>
</html>
```

The next page `home.xhtml` is also using `base.xhtml` in the same way as `index.xhtml` is using it... Below is the snippet of it-

```
<ui:composition template="/template/common/base.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <ui:define name="center">

    <!--  -->
    <!--  -->
    <!--  -->
    <!--  -->
    <!--  -->
    <!--  -->
    <!--  -->
    <!--  -->
    <!--  -->
    <!--  -->
    <!--  -->
    <!--  -->
    <!--  -->
    <!--  -->


    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: Could you share index.xhtml?

Comment: Ya sure... Let me edit my question...

Comment: Could you set property `ajax=false` for commandButton that invokes `#{client.login}` method inside index.xhtml?

Comment: @ÖmerFarukAlmalı: Dude It's working now....  `ajax="false"` So do you mean wherever `action` attribute is being used , we should use `ajax=false`?

Comment: I am going to answer the question :)

Comment: My Problem is resolved from [this post][1], May be this helps you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932446/how-to-use-primefaces-pgrowl-and-redirect-to-a-page?rq=1

Comment: My Problem is resolved by [this post][1], May be this helps you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932446/how-to-use-primefaces-pgrowl-and-redirect-to-a-page?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If a parent of the  with the UICommand button is been
>   rendered/updated by an ajax request beforehand, then the first action
>   will always fail. The second and subsequent actions will work. This is
>   caused by a bug in view state handling which is reported as JSF spec
>   issue 790 and fixed in JSF 2.2. For JSF 2.0 and 2.1 you need to
>   explicitly specify the ID of the  in the render of the
>   `<f:ajax>`

Says BalusC [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2120183/1659451). So in your case you are doing navigation to another page and stucks into that view state bug, `ajax=false` indicates submit the button without AJAX that's why it works.

Also BalusC suggests to use a script which fixes this bug [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408130/jsf-commandbutton-works-on-second-click)