# p:growl doesn't work after JSF page forward, but works with page redirect

Tags: redirect, jsf-2, primefaces, forward

I have created a small JSF web project with primefaces 4.0.

I use a basic template, which contains the header and footer. In the header there is a button which shows a growl message (p:growl element) when he gets pressed.

In the project there are following files:

- index.xhtml: Contains two buttons, which redirects/forwards to another page

All other pages uses the basic template (include header and footer).

If I press the button on the **redirect.xhtml** page **everything is okay** and the message is shown correctly, but If I press the button on the *forward.xhtml* page, *nothing happens*.

I created a simple eclipse project which you can find here: [GrowlRedirectForward.zip](http://www.file-upload.net/download-8480879/GrowlRedirectForward.zip.html)

Answer (score 0):

Problem could be the way redirect and forward works behind the scenes. Have a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932446/how-to-use-primefaces-pgrowl-and-redirect-to-a-page?rq=1) for a potential solution.

Comment: I tried that before, but that do not slove my problem. It is really strange that I lose the message due a page forward. Normally messages are lost due to a page redirect.