# p:growl not working after forward from p:commandButton

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm trying to use a simple `<p:commandButton/>` with an action that forwards to another page and displays a `<p:growl/>`. But when I click my `<p:commandButton/>` it just forwards to the page without displaying the `<p:growl/>`. I looked over some sample codes from other projects and everything checks out, with the exception that I'm using pretty-faces on this particular project but after removing it for a simple test it didn't make a difference either.

This is the closest I could find to my problem:  [p:growl doesn't work after JSF page forward, but works with page redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925097/pgrowl-doesnt-work-after-jsf-page-forward-but-works-with-page-redirect).

Except mine doesnt work with redirect either, apart from that one question. Most of the content I found was about not working with redirect.

My `forward.xhtml` looks like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
 <h:head>
      </h:head>

      <h:form id="form">
        <p:growl id="growl" />
                   <!-- Some other code -->
                    <p:commandButton value="Simple Button" 
                    action="#{forwardPageBean.forward()}" 
                    update=":form:growl" ajax="false" />

         </h:form>
  </html>
```

The page I'm forwarding to: `homePage.xhtml`

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
 <h:head>
      </h:head>

      <h:form id="form">
                   <!-- Some other code -->
         </h:form>
  </html>
```

And my managedBean looks like this:

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class ForwardPageBean implements Serializable{

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

       public String forward(){
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Random message", null));
        return "homePage.xhtml";

         }

  }
```

Here's what I tried so far:

I realize this is used for when you're doing a redirect and want to keep the message but I thought I should try it out.

```
            context.getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
```

I tried changing to actionListener for a simple test and it works.But since it's not made for navigation, doesn't actually solve my problem.

```
 <p:commandButton value="Simple Button" 
                    actionListener="#{forwardPageBean.forward()}" 
                    update=":form:growl" ajax="false" />
```

And lastly, I tried using both actionListener and action in my `<p:commandButton/>` and even though the actionListener method is correctly executed and the forward action happens, it still doesn't display the `<p:growl/>`

```
 <p:commandButton value="Simple Button" action = "homePage.xhtml"
                        actionListener="#{forwardPageBean.forward()}" 
                        update=":form:growl" ajax="false" />



     public void forward(){
         FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
         context.getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
         context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Random message", null));
         }
```

Comment: Most likely not related but `update=":form:growl" ajax="false"` is weird. `update` is useless when not using ajax. Did you check if the there was something in the code html, just not displayed? Did you try using a `p:messages` instead? An `h:messages`? Doing this you can narrow down the real cause. And please try making an [mcve]. It helps you narrow down the problem and others to (very easily) try to reproduce. Now there could be things in the template that play a role that are not visible. This does not mean you should post the template but try to reproduce without it.

Comment: @Kukeltje Made a few changes to my .xhtml code posted to make it easier to run. I did try h:messages and p:messages both and I still get the same behaviour as p:growl. Also tried without my template and the message still isnt shown.

Comment: weird. All seems good. Will try tonight

Comment: Added also the page I'm forwarding to. `homePage.xhtml`

Comment: Uhhhmmmm no idea why I missed this, but you forward to homePage.xhtml and that page has no growl... Sure there is no warning in the log file of the server that there is a message that cannot be displayed?

Comment: Just checked the log file and there was no message warning in it. But you're right, missed `<p:growl/>` on the page I was forwarding to. Everything working as it should be now. Thank you.